# to add class to neighbour html element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add the class `fas fa-exclamation-circle` to `span` tag

```js
$("#gpsno").closest('span').addClass('fas fa-exclamation-circle');
```

```html
<input id="gpsno" class="form-control " type="text">
<span class="form-control-feedback"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$("#gpsno").siblings('span').addClass('fas fa-exclamation-circle');
```

[.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) looks at all the elements' ancestors.

[.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) looks at their siblings.

Comment: Can you have any suggestion to add this span tag inside the input field. No its displaying outside the field

Comment: @vigneshbaskar That depends on the styling of those element. Generally, you'll set it's position to `relative` and change it's `top` and `left` or `right` position.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `.next()` to target the next element

```js
$("#gpsno").next('span').addClass('fas fa-exclamation-circle');
```

```css
.fas {
  color: red
}

.fa-exclamation-circle {
  font-size: 19px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="gpsno" class="form-control " type="text">
<span class="form-control-feedback">123</span>
<span class="">123</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a class to the next neighboring html element (in this case the span), you should replace 'closest' with 'next'.

From the documentation, we can see that 'closest' looks at the ancestor elements of the set it was called on to find a match to the selector while 'next' simply retrieves the next subsequent (sibling) element in the document matching the selector.

Answer (score 0):

directly applied add class on span class selector

```
$('.form-control-feedback').addClass('fas fa-exclamation-circle');
```